# Azure pipeline env variable has cached/stale value

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I wrote a pipeline task with a variable passed like this

```yaml
    jobs:
      - job: buildandpush
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo sanity check
              echo $NOTING_SERVICE_ORIGIN
              echo $NOTING_SERVICE_ORIGIN_2
            env:
              NOTING_SERVICE_ORIGIN: dummy-string-111
              NOTING_SERVICE_ORIGIN_2: dummy-string-222
```

What I see printed is:

```
sanity check
https://some-url-we-used-in-the-past/
dummy-string-222
```

I did not ever add any variables through Azure DevOps UI. The value `https://some-url-we-used-in-the-past/` is no longer anywhere in the codebase. I could not find anything interesting in Azure Pipelines docs.
Is Azure Pipelines caching `NOTING_SERVICE_ORIGIN` somewhere?

Comment: try the pipeline with system diagnostics and check...

Comment: Maybe you have an old variable group specified in the yml pipeline, which still contains the old values?

Check for:
variables:
 - group: <name-of-a-var-group>

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding someone else already defined the variable for the pipeline. Surprising was that it took precedence over the same variable passed explicitly on the spot.